# Destructors After creating several "Symbols" I get an "Automation Error" I believe that I have several instance of the form in memory

Tags: excel, vba

```
   Public Sub InitalizeClass(SacarioSymbol As GroupShapes)
      Dim obfrmGetSymbolName As New frmGetSymbolName
      obfrmGetSymbolName.Show
      Set Symbol = SacarioSymbol
      SymbolName = obfrmGetSymbolName.getSymbolName

     Do While obLibrary.qryNameInUse(SymbolName) = True
         MsgBox "Symbol Name " & SymbolName & " Is in use Please Select Another Name"
         obfrmGetSymbolName.Show
         SymbolName = obfrmGetSymbolName.getSymbolName
         Set Symbol = SacarioSymbol
     Loop
     obLibrary.addSymbol Me
   End Sub
```

in the code above, an instance of a form is created with " Dim obfrmGetSymbolName As New frmGetSymbolName" inside the class frmGetSymbolName I have included the function"

```
   Private Sub Class_Terminate()
      MsgBox "Menue class terminated."
   End Sub
```

this function is never called and after the creation of several symbols, I get an "automation Error"  I believe I have several Instances of this form out in "no mans land"

any direction in mater would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I cannot understand your question and what do you want accomplishing... `Private Sub Class_Terminate()` inside `frmGetSymbolName` form code module does not have any event signification. it is an ordinary `Sub` which must be called in order to run. It should be `Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()` to automatically be triggered. The mentioned `Symbol` is not declared and we do not know anything about its type. We can only deduce that it should be of `GroupShapes` type. `obLibrary` is not declared, we do not know what its `qryNameInUse` method does. No termination is done in your code, too.

Comment: Where does `Public Sub InitalizeClass` exist? What `Me` in the context of the code does mean? Should it be the form instance?